# Conditional probability when both sets measure zero

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a sample space $\Omega = [0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$, and I have two events $A = \{0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1\}$ and $B = \{0, 1/2, 1\}$.

Then it seems clear that $P(B | A) = 3/5$.

The rule I have seen for computing conditional probability is $P(B|A) = P(B \cap A)/P(A)$ when $P(A) \neq 0$.

However, in my case $P(A) = 0$. I am able to compute the conditional probability by approaching from a different direction.

Is there a general rule on how to compute these conditional probabilities?

Comment: These links might help. https://jmanton.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/sets-of-measure-zero-in-probability/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional probabilities given event $A$ are not defined if $P(A)=0$.  However (to answer a question you **didn't** ask but might be lurking in the background), there is such a thing as  conditional probabilities given a continuous random variable, even though the probability of that random variable taking a particular value is $0$.

Comment: So in my example of A and B, even with the uniform metric I cannot say P(B | A) = 3/5?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $P(A|B)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ only when $P(B)>0$. If $P(B)\neq0$ then $P(A|B)$ is given "any" arbitrary value, but just to be clean, define $P(A|B)=0$.

By the way, in your given example, I do not understand one *crucial* thing: what is your probability measure?

Comment: Hrm, well I guess I am assuming my measure is uniform. In that case is my evaluation of $P(B | A) = 3/5$ wrong? Seems straightforward. But infinite sample spaces are weird I guess.